How to match only the first occurence in each file?
I have hundreds of .csv files and each might have up to several hundred lines.
Now I would like to remove the empty lines, e.g. lines of all commas (,,,)
For example, a csv file has content as
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
a,b,c,d
,,,
aa,bb,cc,dd
,,,
,,,
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
,,,
,,,
,,,

, there are hundreds of lines in the file, and I would like to update it to
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
a,b,c,d
aa,bb,cc,dd
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd

, and there are hundreds of such files.
Normally I could match using vim pattern folders then cdo g/pattern/d | update | edit # to remove these lines.
In this removing empty .csv lines case, that would be vim /\v,*$/ folders and cdo g/\v^,*$/d.
However, as there could be hundreds of matches in one file, Vim replace and save the file for each matched position.
Is there a way to match only the first occurence of the pattern in each file in scope?
I tried 1vim but seems this will only return one match in all the files in scope.

what about :cfdo?

vim is absolutely the wrong tool for this job. There are dozens of Linux tool that can easily and efficiently deal with this. Post this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

@user167612 I'm not familiar with linux, basically i'm only using git in bash in windows... is it still possible to achieve the task there?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

@VivianDeSmedt not really, all 3 answers look good, it's just for me to try them and learn something. for user167612's suggestion above, i'll probably raise a question in unix forum separately.

Good to hear :-) Don't hesitate to comment our answers if something is not clear or not working as expected.

Combining :cdo with :global is usually slow; typically one uses :cfdo with :global instead.
The issue with writing the file is additionally that :global sees :update for each line: you could do either of
:cfdo execute 'global//delete' | update

or
:set hidden
:cdo delete
:wall

to avoid multiple nested loops each writing the file.

You can still match all the "empty" lines in all files but use :cfdo instead of :cdo to process all the files with your :g and :update commands.
:cfdo would go over each file instead of each item in the quick fix, so you only delete empty lines and then update/save each file once.
As for the title question -- you can't do it with built in vimgrep, but if you use default system :grep you can supply max count -m 1 parameter:
:grep -m 1 "pattern" *.csv


If is the first occurrence you could uses a range:
:/^,*$/d

Or to be safe if the cursor is not at the top od the file:
:silent! /\%^//^,*$/d

Or namely:
:argadd *.csv
:argdo /\%^//^,*$/d

Or to expand on the solution of @MaximKim:
:vimgrep /^,*$/ *.csv
:cfdo d


I'm afraid i did not explain the question clearly. I've update the post with an example.

Thanks for the feedback and the example. I have removed the first solution and improved the third that should make it ;-)
